# Preg_replace all but digits and . and ,

Tags: php, preg-replace

I'm trying to preg_replace all but Digits and . and , symbols. From a string,

can be

```
nksdfojsdfjdsfojdsjofsojdfjo213-9sdfknmcfsjozx -xdcv-cv,1239103
```

Output using preg_replace or any other solution would return
just the numbers and allow for comma and dot signs.

To end up with a1,322.44
as 1,322.44

This is what I tried

```
$carPrice=preg_replace('/\D/', '', $carPrice);
```

Would write three more paragraphs if it  is necessary, don't seem to find the answer.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: That's interesting. What is your question?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `[^0-9\.,]` as your matching expression.

Comment: thank you very much, interesting in this case you decided to answer and not to vote down on the question

Comment: You updated the question just fine.  Asking questions takes a bit of practice, just like everything else.  I prefer to answer rather than comment in such situations.

Comment: Escaping dots inside of a character class is not necessary.  Explaining every answer that you post is necessary.

Answer (score 7):

you can use this:

```
preg_replace('#[^0-9\.,]#', '', 'your value');
```

Comment: From Review:  Hi, please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks